# Missing values while calculating weights in R language

Tags: r, survey

I have a problem with raking data with missing values. Missing values can only be found in "plec" column. Could you please help me overcome this problem?

That's the code that I have:

```
library(readxl)
DATASET <- read_excel("C:/Users/Mateusz/Desktop/25.10/Nowy Arkusz programu Microsoft Excel.xlsx")
DATA <- as.data.frame(DATASET)
data.svy.unweighted <- svydesign(ids=~1, data=DATA)
plec.dist <- data.frame(plec=c("k","m"), Freq=nrow(DATA)*c(.49,.51))
miasto.dist  <- data.frame(miasto=c(1,2,3), Freq=nrow(DATA)*c(.64,.12,.24))
wiek.dist  <- data.frame(wiek=c(1,2), Freq=nrow(DATA)*c(.7,.3))
data.svy.rake <- rake(design = data.svy.unweighted,sample.margins <- list(~plec,~miasto,~wiek),population.margins <- list(plec.dist, miasto.dist, wiek.dist))
Error in na.fail.default(list(plec = c("m", "k", "k", "m", "m", "k", "k",  : 
  brakujące wartości w argumencie 'object'
```

Comment: Hi, since we can't access your dataset, your post isn't reproducible. Please check this on how to write a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Give the ouput of `dput(DATA)`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have missing data for the variables in `sample.margins` (as the documentation for `rake` says).  If you don't know which cell some observations are in, you can't work out the raking weights.

Perhaps you want to rake just the observations that have non-missing values. In that case, use `subset` to restrict your design to just those observations before calling `rake`.